# empty array with loop with if statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, innerhtml

I'm trying to do the following and coming across some issues: 
create an empty array 
 Push 2 variables into the empty array
Create a for loop that goes through the two variables
Write an if/elseif statement within the for loop:

Here's my code now:

```
var numberArray = [ ];{
numberArray.push("age", "phoneNumber");
for(var i=0; i<numberArray.length; i++) {
    if(numberArray[i] <=100)
        document.getElementById("age").innerHTML = "Age:" + "Age";
    else if(numberArray[i]>100)
        document.getElementById("phoneNumber").innerHTML = "Phone Number:" + "phoneNumber";
```

Comment: You have some syntax errors in here. What is the error console telling you?

Comment: VS Code doesn't give me any warnings

Comment: How would I properly console log it? console.log(numberArray) or console.log numberArray[i]?

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo here in your snippet, but the `{` in the first line looks like a mistake. And you don't have a closing `}` to end your `for` loop. (You can edit your questions here if it's just a typo).

Comment: Well, you apparently want to evaluate your array element zero as if it were a `Number` type - but it is a string `"age"`. That won't do what you want because comparing `"age"` to `100` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Randy Casburn - how do you properly make age and 100 talk to each other?

Comment: @lewda Could you rewrite what you are trying to do? You've put, 'I wan't to do *this* code', When you should write something like, I am trying to take a set of ages and phone numbers, and I want to list them based on some condition, etc. Then provide your input data, and expected output.

Comment: @MattWay sorry...newbie here. I am making an ID card. Create an empty array, 
Push both the age and phoneNumber variables into your empty array
Create a for loop that will loop through the array
Write an if/elseif statement within the for loop
Check to see if array at index i is less than or equal to 100.
 If it is, use DOM innerHTML to write "Age: " plus the variable age.
Check to see if the Array at index i is greater than 100. If it is, use DOM innerHTML to write "Phone Number: " 
plus the variable phoneNumber

Answer (score 1):

Problems:

- you did not show us the HTML, so I will have to assume that the way you worked with the HTML is correct
- you push into the array strings instead of variables, which clearly breaches the specification
- you try to call push with two values you intend to push
- you try to identify the elements based on their length, which might work in this trivial example, but will fail miserably in real-world work, when you have a lot of fields and the length of a number will not uniquely identify its business logic

`var numberArray = [ ];
    var age = 95;
    var phoneNumber = 123;
    numberArray.push({name: 'age', value: age}, {name: 'phoneNumber', value: phoneNumber});
    for(var i=0; i<numberArray.length; i++) {
        if(numberArray[i].name === 'age')
            document.getElementById("age").innerHTML = "Age:" + "Age";
        else if(numberArray[i].name === 'phoneNumber')
            document.getElementById("phoneNumber").innerHTML = "Phone Number:" + "phoneNumber";
    }`